# Matlab equivalent of scipy's 'vode' and 'zvode' ode routines

Tags: matlab, python, ode

In python I have used the `ode` method from `scipy.integrate`. There I used the `vode`integrator and the `zvode` integrator to solve some numerical odes. I am happy with the solution provided by these methods and would now like to know what the equivalent methods are in matlab.

Im not familiar with the intricacies of odes (stiffness and which solvers are suitable in each case) I simply want to know if there is an equivalent matlab routine to the above two integrator methods which I can readily use.

Here is an example of how I have defined a function which should march forward in time

```
def time_march2(y0, x1_max):

   y0 = np.asarray(y0)
   t0 = 0
   tlimit = 100.0 

   backend = 'vode'  
   solver = ode(f2).set_integrator(backend, nsteps=1)
   solver.set_initial_value(y0, t0)
   # suppress Fortran-printed warning
   solver._integrator.iwork[2] = -1

   solution_y = [y0]
   solution_t = [t0]
   warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)

   while solver.successful() and solver.y[0] < x1_max and solver.t < tlimit:
      solver.integrate(tlimit, step=True)          
      solution_y.append(solver.y)
      solution_t.append(solver.t)


   warnings.resetwarnings()
   solution_y = np.array(solution_y)
   solution_t = np.array(solution_t)


   return solution_t, solution_y
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use base MATLAB routines, `ode15s` is the closest analogue (see [Shampine's paper](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/otherdocs/ode_suite.pdf)), although you have to set options to ensure that it uses a BDF method instead of the default NDF method.

If you just want a MATLAB interface, [SUNDIALS](http://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/main.html) has a MATLAB interface to CVODE; CVODE is an updated version of VODE.